# Not able to install node module for SQLite 3 on Windows

Tags: windows, sqlite, node.js

Is someone aware of the steps that are necessary for installing node module for SQLite3?

Cannot see any posts/threads that clearly tell the steps.

I also need to do this without installing Visual Studio etc.

Comment: `npm install sqlite` should be sufficient what have you  tried so far?

Comment: I have tried npm intsall sqlite but it gives some errors.The driver for sqllite is not purely in javascript and hence requires Visual Studio to be installed in Windows.After installing Visual Studio there are lot of tweaks to be done.

Answer (score 2):

and old post, but still relevant. The sqlite3 module relies on the node-gyp module, which on windows is a pain to install. Its readme recently got updated to explain the steps required to make this work, see https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/blob/master/README.md